# KCFINDER: can upload images but cant display

Tags: file-management, kcfinder

after 48hours trying to get a solution i'm exausted.
I use CKEDITOR integrated in my cms to let user get rich text. I integrated KCFINDER (opensource file manager) to let user upload images and insert inside his textareas.

Now, on my local server all works fine (upload and display images), but when i start the same process in remote server i get problems: can perfectly **upload images** (which i check via Ftp and in KCFINDER browser) but i **can't display** them in the preview and in my site neither with direct access (like: http://www.myserver.net/images/image01.jpg). I always get this error:

"**500 Internal Server Error**

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@myserver.net to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

In the server log i got this error:
Wed May 21 17:01:35 2014] [alert] [client 87.15.86.157:49658] - www.myserver.net - /web/htdocs/www.myserver.net/home/images/upload/.htaccess: Option ExecCGI not allowed here

If i delete .htaccess file inside upload folder i can get preview image and all works, but everytime i upload a new image the .htaccess fil in regenerated and i get the same problem.

I tried changing uploadDir and uploadURL like 300times, changed permission all to 777 and followed instructions 3 times on clean installation but i can't get off this.

Answer (score 1):

I see that your question is two years old, But I will post my answer as it may help any new searcher for the same problem.

I faced the same problem and could finally solve it..

The problem was that Kcfinder adds a .htaccess file in your uploads directory.
this htaccess file contains a line "   Options -ExecCGI " that is not allowed in some hosts, so when this htaccess is added, the images in your uploaded directory are now displayed ( and your image that is uploaded from the kcfinder as well)

The solution is to prevent KCfinder from adding this .htacess file.
This is easy by goiing to kcfinder/conf/config.php
you will find this line :
'_check4htaccess' => true,

Change it to be false

That's it.

Comment: This is the right answer. Have been struggling with this a few times already, and kept forgetting about it. Thanks!